# How should my classes look from this xml using xmlserializer?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

This is the xml i get back from a third part api :

```
<data>
    <installations>
        <installation>
            <reader>1</reader>
            <reader>2</reader>
            <reader>3</reader>
            <reader>4</reader>
        </installation>
    </installations
</data>
```

And these are the classes I have for now

```
public class data
{
    public List<installation> installations
}

public class installation
{
    // HERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO THE <reader> STUFF
}
```

I hope someone knows how this should be done

/Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes could look like this:

```
public class data
{
    public List<installation> installations { get; set; }
    public data() { installations = new List<installation>(); }
}

public class installation
{
    [XmlElement("reader")]
    public List<reader> reader { get; set; }
    public installation() { reader = new List<reader>(); }
}

public class reader
{
    [XmlTextAttribute]
    public Int32 value {get;set;}
}
```

Two things are important here:

1. the use of `XmlElement("reader")` to hide the `<reader></ reader>` nodes that would otherwise created due to the `List<reader> reader` property.
2. the use of `XmlTextAttribute` to have the the `<reader><value>1</value></reader>` created as `<reader>1</reader>`.

Comment: Thanks alot, that did the trick. One can always learn something new ;o)

Comment: One question though, why does XmlElement("reader") hide the <reader> element, is that because it is of type List<reader>?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `XSD.exe` to create the classes for you automatically:

```
REM Infer XSD from XML
xsd.exe myfile.xml

REM Create classes from XSD
xsd.exe myfile.xsd /classes
```

Comment: I know that, but as the content in <installation> changes regarding on the request i make, this isn't as easy as it look's. But thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @websam If the content of `<installation>` changes arbitrarily between requests, then it is not possible for you to write any class that will capture it. Basically, if you cannot generate a schema, you cannot generate a class, as a class is just a representation of the schema.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class data 
{
List<List<reader>> installations = new List<List<reader>>();
List<reader> installation = new List<reader>();
installation.Add(new reader());
installation.Add(new reader());
installation.Add(new reader());
installation.Add(new reader());
installations.Add(installation);
}
```

or

```
public class data
{
    public List<installation> installations
}

public class installation : List<reader>
{
    public void AddReader(reader obj)
    {
        this.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

and other way, without using XmlSerializer(typeof(UnknownClass)) is custom parsing the xml:

with LINQ to Xml;

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlTextFromThirdParty);
```

Comment: As the amount of <reader> can change from request to request this is not the way to do it.